# SSH not working with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh

I recently bought a RPI2 to play with; at first I've installed OSMC and RetroPie in dual boot, but now I had to switch back to Raspbian to setup a local webserver.
The problem is that I'm actually unable to use the SSH connection from my MB Pro or Android phone.
The RPI is connected to my WLAN and is able to connect outside my lan (pinging google works flawlessly) but not inside my lan (pinging my MBP is impossible).
The raspberry is able to self-ssh.
I've tried googling the issue but no solution has been found by now...
One last thing, i've tried sniffing my lan with lanscan and the RPI seems not to be connected to the lan even when actually connected LOL.
Any idea?

Comment: Did you enable SSH in `sudo raspi-config`?

Comment: ssh is enabled by default, is a fresh install... anyway i reenabled in raspi-config, just to doublecheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the interfaces file and I found two wlan interfaces instead of one.
The file was

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I changed to:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off

#auto wlan1
#allow-hotplug wlan1
#iface wlan1 inet manual
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

using the command `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
you could delete the wlan1 part, I commented just for caution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like more of a problem with the network.

Is the Pi in the same network/subnet even?

check with :

```
$ ifconfig
```

check your router should there be a discrepancy.

Comment: checked on the router, they are connected to the same network, i don't have a subnet...
http://it.tinypic.com/r/uvg9y/8

Comment: check your firewall settings on the Pi, mac and router, perhaps one of them is blocking.

Comment: do you know where the pis firewall config are? mac and router should be fine, when using OSMC on RPI everything was fine...
anyway i cannot use ssh even from PI to MBP...